# Woocommerce remove custom data when remove a product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have added custom fields with every product. But when user remove a product from cart then session of these custom fields did not remove. I want to remove custom fields according to product. Please help me.

```
 <?php         add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_item_quantity_zero','wdm_remove_user_custom_data_options_from_cart',1,1);
 if(!function_exists('wdm_remove_user_custom_data_options_from_cart'))
 {
 function wdm_remove_user_custom_data_options_from_cart($cart_item_key)
 {
    global $woocommerce;
    // Get cart
    $cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    // For each item in cart, if item is upsell of deleted product, delete it
    foreach( $cart as $key => $values)
    {


    if ( $values['wdm_user_custom_data_value'] == $cart_item_key )

        print_r($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[ $key ]);
        //unset( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[ $key ] );
    }


  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_item_quantity_zero','wdm_remove_user_custom_data_options_from_cart',1,1);
if(!function_exists('wdm_remove_user_custom_data_options_from_cart'))
{ 
    function wdm_remove_user_custom_data_options_from_cart($cart_item_key)
    { 
        global $woocommerce;
        // Get cart
        $cart = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
        // For each item in cart, if item is upsell of deleted product, delete it
        foreach( $cart as $key => $values)
        {  
            if ( $_REQUEST['remove_item'] == $key )
            { 
                unset( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[ $key ] );
            }
        } 
    }
}
```